# How to find the general solution to a system of linear First order Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
Am I supposed to use matrices for the system of equations above? If not how should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrices. Your matrix is $A=\begin{pmatrix}4&0&-1\\2&2&-1\\3&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ which has characteristic polynomial $\chi_A=(X-2)^3$.  It can be checked this has a Jordan form $$\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\1&2&0\\0&1&2\end{pmatrix}$$ which will give a system $X'=CJC^{-1}X$, which can be solved by the change of variables $Y=C^{-1}X$. The real work is in finding a Jordan base, that is, obtaining $C$.

**ADD** To obtain $B$, it suffices to exhibit -- in this case -- an element $v\notin \ker A'^2$ and consider $B=\{v,A'v,A'^2v\}$ where $A'=A-2I$. Since $$A'^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\1&-1&0\\2&-2&0\end{pmatrix}$$ such an element is $e_1$. Then our Jordan basis is $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\{(1,0,0),(2,2,3),(1,1,2)\}$, and it can be checked $|A|_B$ has the above form.

Comment: You made an error in $A$, in location $a_{23}$.

Comment: @Amzoti Drats. =)

Comment: Is those darn subscripts of variables! :-)

Comment: I thought Jordan form of the matrix is its diagonalizable matrix only if the matrix is actually diagonalizable? But in this case, the eigenvalues are not distinct.  They are all 2. So the matrix is not diagonalizable. Or did I misunderstood my class lecture?

Comment: @Nasser The matrix $2I$ has only one eigenvalue $2$, but it is diagonalizable. What is your confusion?

Comment: Ok, I checked the text book. My confusion is that our textbook said only where the matrix A of size N by N, has  N linearly independent eigenvectors, only then the matrix A is diagonalizable. I thought first that since the eigenvalues are the same, then the eigenvectors can't be L.I., but this is not necessarly the case. A can have same eigevalues, but still have L.I. eigevectors.